# How do I compare two hex codes including # and make them lower case in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, hex, string-comparison

When comparing two hex codes it does not recognise #ffffff and #FFFFFF as equal. Is there a way of formatting the #FFFFFF to lower case somehow?

The hex codes could be totally random and I cannot use the lower-case() function from XSLT 2.0 as I'm using V.1. I found several potential answers here with translate(), but none of them seem to work.

Here is how I compare:

```
    <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$current_node_backgroundcolor = $preceding_node_backgroundcolor">
            (...)
```

I'd appreciate any kind of help! Thanks!

Comment: translate() *is* the answer here. Post some actual code that we can use to show you how.

Comment: Isn't the code above enough? I need to compare these two variables in lower case. Both of them could be either lower or upper case.

Comment: then use the translate as : translate($current_node_backgroundcolor, 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'), and same for $preceding_node_backgroundcolor.

Comment: ouw that's how translate() works. cool thanks, that did the job!

Comment: "*Isn't the code above enough?*" It's not enough to test the answer before posting..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<xsl:when test="translate($current_node_backgroundcolor, 'ABCDEF', 'abcdef') = translate($preceding_node_backgroundcolor, 'ABCDEF', 'abcdef')">
```

Comment: Actually, you had the real right answer, as hex codes are in hexadecimal, no need to go further than F, good call ! :-)